# Problem with changing font and position of axis labels and tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following code below!

I am trying to do 3 things:

1. Change the **distance** between the X/Y-axis and their respective labels and **centre** the title of the graph
2. Change the **rotation angle** of the tick labels on the X-axis to 45 degrees
3. **Bolden** the font of the x and y-axis labels and of the legend title

```
positiveplot = ggplot(positiveaffect, aes(x=factor(Time), y=Scores, fill = Group)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + labs(title="Change in self-rated positive affect", x="Time", y = "Positive Affect Score")
+ theme(legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), axis.text.x = element_text((vjust = -2), angle = 45), axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = -2))  + scale_x_discrete(labels=labelspositive) + theme_classic()
```

The output I get is as follows:

[image]

I would be so grateful if anyone could give me a helping hand!

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
structure(list(Group = c("SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", "SH", 
"SH", "SH", "SH", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", 
"HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC", "HC"), Time = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3), Scores = c(18, 24, 31, 11, 14, 23, 17, 32, 19, 10, 
35.6378909726158, 16, 22, 19, 19, 23, 20, 34, 17, 29, 12, 20, 
16, 30, 26, 18, 21, 20, 15, 28, 29.3521832998335, 16, 10, 15, 
17, 21, 14, 23, 12, 28, 17, 22, 13, 17, 13, 17, 16, 18, 19, 11, 
17, 16, 24, 20, 22, 19, 18, 18, 15, 28.0883375096763, 20, 10, 
11, 13, 10, 28.0883375096763, 16, 11, 22, 10, 16, 10, 13, 12, 
16, 16, 15, 17, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 10, 18, 24, 26, 41, 25, 32, 
13, 13, 28, 10, 24, 32, 36, 17, 16, 25, 38, 27, 28, 18, 14, 18, 
30, 27, 24, 19, 33.2978283948586, 24, 24, 14, 20, 20, 10, 22, 
15, 12, 24, 20, 26, 21, 20, 17, 11, 24, 10, 21, 24, 27, 22, 34.0925216652814, 
24, 25, 12, 15, 24, 18, 23, 27, 14, 13, 11, 21, 25, 20, 22, 15, 
11, 17, 10, 20, 27), ID = c("1222", "1992j", "1992i", "1592", 
"1602", "1192", "1852", "1422", "1732", "1999", "1924", "1812", 
"1752", "1762", "1782", "19992", "1892", "199912", "190", "171", 
"199924", "1912", "199943", "1982", "1802", "3812", "199945", 
"197", "1492", "1222", "1992j", "1992i", "1592", "1602", "1192", 
"1852", "1422", "1732", "1999", "1924", "1812", "1752", "1762", 
"1782", "19992", "1892", "199912", "190", "171", "199924", "1912", 
"199943", "1982", "1802", "3812", "199945", "197", "1492", "1222", 
"1992j", "1992i", "1592", "1602", "1192", "1852", "1422", "1732", 
"1999", "1924", "1812", "1752", "1762", "1782", "19992", "1892", 
"199912", "190", "171", "199924", "1912", "199943", "1982", "1802", 
"3812", "199945", "197", "3212", "3182", "3162", "3412", "3492", 
"1993", "363", "3362", "3122", "3152", "1997", "19995", "330", 
"370", "3999", "19998", "375", "374", "373", "377", "379", "380", 
"382", "3212", "3182", "3162", "3412", "3492", "1993", "363", 
"3362", "3122", "3152", "1997", "19995", "330", "370", "3999", 
"19998", "375", "374", "373", "377", "379", "380", "382", "3212", 
"3182", "3162", "3412", "3492", "1993", "363", "3362", "3122", 
"3152", "1997", "19995", "330", "370", "3999", "19998", "375", 
"374", "373", "377", "379", "380", "382")), row.names = c(NA, 
-155L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
# A tibble: 100 x 4
   Group  Time Scores ID   
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
 1 SH        1     18 1222 
 2 SH        1     24 1992j
 3 SH        1     31 1992i
 4 SH        1     11 1592 
 5 SH        1     14 1602 
 6 SH        1     23 1192 
 7 SH        1     17 1852 
 8 SH        1     32 1422 
 9 SH        1     19 1732 
10 SH        1     10 1999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will solve your issues:

```
positiveplot = ggplot(positiveaffect,
                      aes(x = factor(Time),
                          y = Scores,
                          fill = Group)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  labs(title="Change in self-rated positive affect",
       x="\nTime",
       y = "Positive Affect Score\n") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -2, angle = 45, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(vjust = -2, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labelspositive)
```

Comment: How can I also make the axis labels bold (as well as just the tick labels as above)? :)

Comment: And for some reason, the Y-axis distance from text to graph does not seem to be changing - I've tried using 'hjust' rather than 'just' but that still does not work?

Comment: Thanks for including the MRE. You can turn the axis titles bold by adding `axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")` to your `theme()`, and I made a mistake with the y-axis; changing `y = "\nPositive Affect Score"` to`y = "Positive Affect Score\n"` should give you the outcome you want. I've updated my answer to reflect these changes

Comment: Thanks so much! It all works really well now :)